# How do I migrate from the Google Email Migration API to the Gmail API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-email-migration

The Google Email Migration API v1 is scheduled to be shut down on April 20, 2015 and v2 is already deprecated. I need to migrate my code to use the Gmail API instead, how do I go about this migration?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-emapi) determine you how to translate calls to the Email Migration API to their corresponding calls in the Gmail API. Refer to the Gmail API’s documentation for information on how to download libraries and get started.

Be aware that support for older authorization methods ([ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps), [AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthSub), and [OAuth 1.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref)) are also scheduled to be shut down at the same time. If you are currently using these methods please also migrate to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) at the same time.